# jquery detect user scrolling to bottom firing too early

Tags: jquery, scroll

I need to detect when a user has scrolled to the bottom of my page. So I searched around a bit and found a lot of help, all with basically the same answer, just maybe slightly varied. I've tried out basically all the different versions that I could find, but all of them exhibit the same behavior. Instead of waiting for me to scroll to the bottom of my page (actually have the scroll bar go all the way to the bottom), it fires when I scroll just a tiny bit. So my scroll bar will have moved only a cm or less, and the event fires.

The code I'm using right now is from here [stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/how-to-check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom)

There are two versions in the accepted answer there and the first one doesn't actually fire at all.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {         
        //do stuff
    }
})
```

However, if I change it to the second version (even setting the offset to 0) it fires, but it fires much too early. Before the user actually scrolled to the bottom.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
       //do stuff
   }
});
```

Now this isn't a huge issue, I think I can live with it, but it is really annoying. Does anybody have any idea what I might be doing wrong? I'm testing in Chrome, but the same behavior is exhibited in Firefox.

Thanks!

Comment: This jsFiddle (on your previous question) is working: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gWD66/1/

Comment: You're right that does work. However, I just copy pasted that code into mine, and it alerts me saying "bottom" every single time I scroll. Not just at the bottom. And I don't know why.

Comment: Maybe you can try to check/alert the values of `$(windows).scrollTop()`, `$(window).height()` and `$(document).height()`? Probably one is returning zero?

Comment: it seems that window.height and document.height are always the same. Like this:scrollTop:  49
window height:  680
document height:  680

scrollTop:  149
window height:  2739
document height:  2739

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your html has the DOCTYPE set by making the first line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Ref:
[Jquery $(window).height() function does not return actual window height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787380/jquery-window-height-function-does-not-return-actual-window-height)

Comment: It seems that you are correct! I used to have <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC> and that was screwing it all up. But now its all fixed! Thanks!