# Scroll Function working in reverse order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am calling a function when user scroll to the bottom.

In my case function is called when scroll reaches top instead of bottom. Working in reverse order.

Make a file with name " scroll.html " and copy my code below and past it in that file. You will find the bug

Please help fixing this issue in file instead of fiddle.

Because my code works perfect in fiddle. I want to know what is the problem with my document ?

**Code :**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(document).height() == $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
            alert('You\'ve reached the bottom');
        }
    });
});
</script>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please do make an HTML file of it. And then test it.**

Comment: Please post a fiddle and code example in your post. Providing a link to a website which might not be there in a few minutes, hours, days is useless for future visitors. So please post your code, and a link to a demo that will exist for longer than a few days (for example on jsfiddle).

Comment: Can you show the code that has the problem? Don't link to external files. Also, your link doesn't work.

Comment: @CodeHunter Please post a fiddle and code example in your post. Providing a link to a website which might not be there in a few minutes, hours, days is useless for future visitors. So please post your code, and a link to a demo that will exist for longer than a few days (for example on jsfiddle).

Comment: Post the code or make a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net "JSFiddle").

Comment: In fiddle it works fine. as I mentioned in my post. But it doesnt works in my file. Please download this file

Comment: I am not downloading your file @CodeHunter ....

Comment: Just post the code and we'll help if we can.

Comment: Allright I am posting whole page code

Comment: Please check my post now

Comment: You're right in the Fiddle works ok.

Comment: Please do make an HTML file of it. And then test it. It will not work in html file

Comment: @CodeHunter Try debugging on your side, is $(window).height() the value you expect???

Comment: I put your script just before the `</body>` tag in one of my templates and it works like it should but without `$(document).ready(function () {`.

Comment: @A.Wolff Basically the is issue is something else, this code works fine on fiddle, but not on simple html document. Please copy my code and past it in an html file. than check, it will work in reverse order

Comment: @mdesdev Can you put the code in answer please ?

Comment: It's your code just without `$(document).ready(function () { });`.

Comment: @CodeHunter no, this is your issue on your site!!! $(window).height() is not the expected value. And no, i won't download any file to debug your awful code, i'm afraid

Comment: @A.Wolff There is no site at all, just an HTML file. Did you check it in html file ? Just copy my code

Comment: @CodeHunter i din't post your previous question where you posted your online site as duplicate, should I?

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes but now its not even working on simple plain and clean html file.

Comment: So provide a jsfiddle. I know you will tell it works on jsfiddle so maybe your issue is related to some CSS rule. And here we go, have you try setting body height: `body{height:100%}` Try and see

Comment: @A.Wolff My code works perfect in fiddle. But it doesnt works in simple html file. All you have to do is to make an html file with name : scroll.html and copy code from my post and past it in that html file. You will find the bug

Comment: @mdesdev Problem not solved with that either

Comment: I already do that and your code works just fine both in the Fiddle and in the one of my templates + on that template I have 1000+ lines of jQuery.

Comment: Please copy your whole working code and past it in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your window height is not returning expected value, because you are not setting any DOCTYPE:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

[SEE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787380/jquery-window-height-function-does-not-return-actual-window-height)