# $(window).height() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, doctype

JQuery Links being used:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var menuBarHeight = $("#menubar").height();
alert(windowHeight);
alert(menuBarHeight);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>...
```

CSS:

```
#menubar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

I have used the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787380/jquery-window-height-function-does-not-return-actual-window-height) as reference, however the solution there doesn't work for me. I'm trying to workout the distance of the window and a menu bar and using the data I will subtract one from the other so as to give me the height to use for another container on the rest of the page.

If it helps I've attached the HTML Doctype tag at the top and have also attached the css stylying of the #menubar. I've tryed on chrome and Firefox on a windows 10 machine.

Comment: If the is exactly what you currently have - you don't have the jquery lib (you have only the jquery-ui lib, and it's not enough).

Comment: The jQuery library :)

Comment: sorry just realised I missed something:...  I've attached this library as well: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Any errors thrown in console? Do elements exist when the code runs? What's in the alerts? A better description than *"doesn't work"* will help

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for your help Dekel realised that local download was not in the correct folder so the JQuery Library wasn't being accessed.

Comment: @shaam that would have been easily detected in your browser console with error *"$ is undefined"* which is most certainly there

Comment: Thanks, I'll take that on board stupid mistake on my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this code (with the correct jquery lib):

```js
$(function() {
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var menuBarHeight = $("#menubar").height();
  alert(windowHeight);
  alert(menuBarHeight);
});
```

```css
#menubar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<div id="menubar"></div>
```