# $(window).height() gives incorrect values on horizontal resize

Tags: jquery

I am using $(window).height(), but when I am resizing the window horizontally, it gives wrong values for just a moment. Lets say first its 974 , then it goes 957, then up again.

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yAnn.png)

Comment: Provide a  [mcve]

Comment: you probably want to check your media query split points, its probably some element floated left which drops below at a particular screen width

Comment: you are right, it must be something like that

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple cases.

1) The most simple one: Add `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` declaration to your HTML page ( http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-window-height-incorrect/ )

2) It is possible that you are checking the console with firebug/ something else. So that you don't get window height correct due to firebug height.

See more info here [why is $(window).height() so wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569301/why-is-window-height-so-wrong)